# I have a dataframe column with list type but some of the rows in column have missing data so I want to drop the missing data rows from the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe column with list type but some of the rows in column have missing data so I want to drop the missing data rows from the column.

```
for i in range(len(data_Re)):
       if type(data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1']) == float:
            data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1'] = data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1'].drop(data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1'], axis=0) 
            print(i)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         2 
>         3            if type(data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1']) == float:
>   ----> 4                 data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1'] = data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1'].dropna(data_Re.ix[i,'Actual CoQ Value1'], axis=0)
>         5                 print(i)
>
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Answer (score 0):

There is a thousand way to do it in only 1 row. Here arre some examples

```py
# Option 1
data_Ref.dropna(subset=['Actual CoQ Value1'],inplace=True)

# Option 2
data_Ref = data_Ref[data_Ref['Actual CoQ Value1'].notnull()]

# Option 3
data_Ref = data_Ref[~data_Ref['Actual CoQ Value1'].isnull()]
```